# Book (or series) about a boy who sees "mirrors"

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book quite a long time ago (5-7 years) and I would love to revisit it but I can't remember the name anymore.

It was a about a boy who saw "mirrors" flowing around. Later on, he found out these mirrors actually were portals where demons came through. At one time a demon came through a portal a ripped his whole class apart.  He had a young brother who got kidnapped but when he went through the portal to save him he found out he never had a little brother and this was a demon too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're describing Kernel Fleck, one of the main protagonists of the [Demonata Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Demonata) by Darren Shan. The plot you describe is that of the second book in the series, *Demon Thief*:

> Kernel Fleck is a lonely child. He has always been different: he can
>   see strange patches of light in the air around him. Other kids think
>   he's mad. But when he manages to link some of the lights together, he
>   creates a window into another universe, and disappears for several
>   days. When he returns, his memory a blank, his panicked parents whisk
>   Kernel and his younger brother, Art, away from their home, off to an
>   isolated village, to start a new life.
>   One year later, Kernel is enjoying himself. Life is good. Until one
>   day a crazy old woman summons a demon. The beast slaughters many of
>   the children, then kidnaps one of them and retreats back to its own
>   universe. The child it has kidnapped is Art.
>
> Can Kernel find the courage to step through the window after the demon
>   in a desperate attempt to rescue his brother? And if so, what wonders
>   and terrors will he discover in the barbaric universe of the evil
>   twisted Demonata?!?

Great series.

Comment: That's the one, awesome thank you very much. I will definitely check out the other two in the series. Are they linked or just separate stories?

Comment: @TJasinski There are 10 books in the series. The first three can be read completely seperately but introduce each of the three protagonists. After that things get... weird but awesome when their lives start to interact with each other and everything forms one big story.

Comment: Great i travel a lot for my work and this will be mine new personal project